# Deep-link directly into a specific chat or message?

Tags: ios, getstream-io

This is for iOS: What method do you recommend for deep-linking directly into a specific chat or message from elsewhere in an app, when I have a channel-id and/or a message-id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recommend using `query` functions to fetch messages/channels by their id.

```swift
// Fetch a channel by id
let query = ChannelsQuery(filter: .key("id", .equal(to: "channel-id")))
Client.shared.channels(query: query).subscribe(onNext: { (response) in
    // handle response
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)

// Fetch a message by id
Client.shared.message(with: "message-id").subscribe(onNext: { (response) in
    // handle response
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Soon we'll release 2.0, which will have support for usual callback-way.

Comment: here what I meant. Example use case: a user tap a push notification that has info about the channel and message. How can I open a channel or message directly from that cold start?

Comment: @Dan you can query the message/channel by its id and then present your Chat screen. Since this is an async operation you can show a loading screen while you wait for the query. When you get the message/channel, if you're using StreamChat's `ChatViewController`, you can initialize a `ChannelPresenter` with the `ChannelResponse` and pass it to the `ChatViewController`, like so:
Inside your `ChatViewController.viewDidLoad`:
`channelPresenter = ChannelPresenter(response: response, queryOptions: .all)`